# Splitting strings into two different columns pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a below data frame called df. It has location column and it is a list separated by a comma.

[image]

Expected output

I need to split the last two strings into multiple columns.

Example Input:

```py
    ['122 Grenfell Street', 'Adelaide CBD', '5000 Adelaide', 'Australia']
```

Example Output:

```
    df['Country']: Australia
    
    
    df['City'] : 5000 Adelaide
```

I need to do the same for all the rows.

I tried below code

```py
df['Country'] = df['Loction'].str.split(',', expand = True)
```

The above code is not working. I tried other posts but not successful

Comment: Have you tried to get properties by index? (`df["Country"] = df["Location"][3]`)

Comment: @Korgan No. I tried with regex but not successful too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) along with the given `regex` pattern:

```
df[['City', 'Country']] = df['Location'].str.extract(r"'([^,']+?)'\s*,\s*'([^'\]]+)'\s*\]")
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

    Location                                            City            Country
0   [122 Grenfell Street, Adelaide CBD, 5000 Adela...   5000 Adelaide   Australia
```

See the regex demo [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/7cyYAJ/2/).

Comment: "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key" getting this error

Comment: @jack1285 So i guess your dataframe contains lists of uneven length, right? Or, Does the column contains nan values?

Comment: yes, it has 12000 records. Sorry I didn't mention. It doesn't have nan

Comment: @jack1285 in that case, we might have to use alternate solution, give me some time...

Comment: @jack1285 If there are empty lists (or list having a single element only) in such case what you want the output in your `City and Country` column?

Comment: OK. it doesn't have nan values

Comment: i need to split the last two strings which is sperated by comma. i need to get the two new columns each as a last two strings from each row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217208/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-jack1285).

Answer (score 1):

Create list by using the `tolist()`. Create datframe using `pd.DataFrame`

Say sample data is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'text':[['122 Grenfell Street', 'Adelaide CBD', '5000 Adelaide', 'Australia']]})
```

Extract list elements into columns:

```
df[['Street','Area','City','Country']] = pd.DataFrame(df.text.tolist(), index= df.index)

                                                text               Street  \
0  [122 Grenfell Street, Adelaide CBD, 5000 Adela...  122 Grenfell Street   

           Area           City    Country  
0  Adelaide CBD  5000 Adelaide  Australia
```